# CKEditor and escaping elements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, escaping, ckeditor, font-awesome

I've using [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) for updating [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) content on my website. I also using FontAwesome, which includes set of fancy icons, that can be displayed like this

```
<i class="icon-envelope"></i>
```

The problem is that CKEditor escapes this `i` tag on client side, and I can't see it in source mode.

How can I allow this tag? I have tried with `CONFIG.removeFormatTags = ''`, but unfortunately it does not do the job.

Comment: i came across the same problem , read here for a solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18254082/1316372

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is removed because it is empty. Put some non-breaking space `&nbsp;` or zero-width space `&#8203;` within it to preserve your tag.

You can also remove `i` from `CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty` object. This may, however, break other empty `<i>` tags without `class="icon-envelope"`. To fix this you would need to play with a [data processor](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) to filter empty `<i>'s` without `class="icon-envelope"`. Pretty easy I guess.

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled already via config.fillEmptyBlocks which is set to true by default?

How does one edit the CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty object to remove the i element? I can't find it listed as being removed anywhere in js files.

I'd like to edit the fillEmptyBlocks function to use &#8203; instead of the non-breaking space. The spacing of icons in font-awesome is only correct when the element remains empty or uses &#8203;

Answer (score 0):

below worked for me.. thanks to Vince Kronlein pointing out config.fillEmptyBlocks

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
       config.fillEmptyBlocks="&#8203;";  
}
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode of `&zwnj;` in situation of html code showing in CKEditor for making Zero-width non-joiner (mini-space) in languages like persian.

می‌خواهم
می‌توانم