# CkEditor deletes Bootstrap <i></i> icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

We have a site built on Bootstrap.

Certain HTML modules are maintained with CkEditor.

We use Bootstrap icons according to standard syntax, e.g.: `<i class="icon-envelope"></i>`.

Our problem: CkEditor interprets that syntax as an empty tag set (i.e., `<i></i>`) and deletes it.

As a result, we currently can't use Bootstrap icons in any HTML modules maintained with CkEditor.

Any solutions out there?  Thanks!

Comment: Identical question was asked few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829961/ckeditor-and-escaping-elements.

Comment: TY Reinmar. That URL didn't mention Bootstrap, thus didn't find it in my searching. I've been searching SO for an answer for a week, so I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: i came across the same problem , read here for a solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18254082/1316372

Answer (score 1):

Paste this in CKEditor config file:

```
// allow i tags to be empty (for font awesome)
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false
```